# How to write the batch file for copying the files from `Windows\SysWOW64` folder to another folder

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I have some required files in the `Windows\SysWOW64` folder that I need to copy to another location using a batch file script.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question ?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `xcopy` or `robocopy`

#### 1. Using `xcopy`

```
xcopy /s /e dir_to_copy dir_to_paste
```

`/s` copies directories as well as it's `sub`directories (except empty ones) and `/e` copies `empty` subdirectories also.

In your case It will be

```
xcopy /s /e C:\windows\syswow64 folder\to\paste
```

#### 2. Using `robocopy`

```
robocopy /COPYALL /E C:\Folder1 D:\Folder2
```

where `/E` means copy subdirectories including `empty` ones.

```
robocopy /MIR C:\Folder1  D:\FOlder2
```

`NOTE` : This creates an exact copy of source folder into destination by `overwriting the contents` of destination folder.

#### 3. Try this script

```
@echo off
::Ask
echo Enter Source Directory to copy :
set SRC=
set /P SRC=Type input: %=%

echo Enter Destination Directory to paste :
set DEST=
set /P DEST=Type input: %=%

xcopy /s /e /y %SRC% %DEST%
```

Feel free to add in more.

Answer (score 2):

**[Robocopy and a few examples](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx)**

**Copy directory structure**

Run the below Robocopy command to copy directory structure i.e deep copy of folder hierarchy and the data in all the subfolders.

```
Robocopy /S D:\dir1\data E:\backup\data
```

This command does not copy empty directories. To copy them, you need to add /E switch.

```
Robocopy /S /E  D:\dir1\data E:\backup\data
```

**Mirror copy a directory**

Below Robocopy command creates a replica of the source folder in the specified destination folder

```
Robocopy /MIR sourceFolder  destinationFolder
```

This command also deletes any extra files that are present in the destination and are not present in source.